# How do I count total instances for my specified criteria

Tags: excel

I want to use a formula, similar to COUNTIF however I can't quite figure it out.

here is some sample data:

[image]

What formula should I use for the 'Total for each criteria function'. I want it to count the entire frequency column but only count its set criteria. So A should have 14 and B should have 17 etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of a formula, you could use a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 2):

`SUMIF` is what you're looking for:

```
=SUMIF([range], [criteria], [sum_range])
```

And in your case, where `D1` is the cell with the matching letter:

```
=SUMIF(B:B, D1, A:A)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this one,

```
=COUNTIF(C6:C11, "A")
```

It will give you 4.

Change "A" to B and C to get the results

Comment: The expected result is 14.